# Sample POST request to create case in sfdc from external System

Tags: apex, integration, json, httprequest

I have a requirement to create a case in our organization from external services.

So, I need the sample json post request to create a case in sfdc. And right now we are in classic edition. So, we didn't register for the domain. How I need to specify endpoint directly like login.salesforce.com

I'm an administrator of my Org. So please guide some one to know the prerequisites to access sfdc from external services

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation on the [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm) or how to [work with records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_working_with_records.htm)?

Comment: Yeah, a little bit confused because it is explained with curl tool to access records. So, shall I access endpoint directly like this with other systems too like https://login.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/case/ -H "Authorization: Bearer token -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@newcase.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, after logging in, you'll be redirected to your org. It is vital that you use only your org-specific URL to interact with the REST API; login.salesforce.com does not handle anything other than login requests. So, for example, if you were me, you'd change your endpoint to something like:

```
https://na3.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/case
```

---

Next, you simply need to POST the data that you want to send. This is what a raw request would look like at the application layer:

```
POST /services/data/v42.0/sobjects/case HTTP/1.1
Host: na3.salesforce.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer 00DXX00000XXXXX!lotsOfRandomLetters.andNumbers
Content-Length: 23

{ Subject: "New Case" }
```

IN the documentation, cURL is often used to demonstrate stuff without being "language specific". Each language you use will have different semantics that you need to go through, but at the end of the day, the request is going to look nearly identical to the above block.

---

One final note: access tokens and session IDs are generally interchangeable. The above example is a finctional session ID, not actually an access token. When you authenticate with the server, use whatever token the server gives to you.